# Outlook VBA: Join two folder objects together for sort/Restrict filter

Tags: vba, outlook

I have two folders of tasks in Outlook. I want to create a single collection from them both that I can use Sort and Restrict on. How do I do this?

E.g.

```
Set FolderTasks1 = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderToDo).Items
Set FolderTasks2 = Application.Session.Accounts("xx@outlook.com").DeliveryStore.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderToDo).Items

[insert magic joining thing here. Call the new collection joinedTasks]

strFilter = Format(Now, "ddddd")
strFilter = "[Start Date] <= " & Chr(34) & strFilter & Chr(34) & " And Not [status] = ""Completed"" And Not [Categories] = ""Project"""
joinedTasks.Sort "[Start Date]"
Set ListOfTasks = joinedTasks.Restrict(strFilter)
```

I've tried looping over both folders and creating a collection but then I lose the ability to Sort and Restrict the collection.

I'm building a tool that'll allow me to review all my tasks in Outlook. I can get it to work for each folder seperately but I want to do it for all tasks in all folders (two different accounts).

Comment: Make a blank Items Collection, then add the items from both Items Collections to that. Here are the docs -- > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.items

Answer (score 0):

Generally, `Items.Sort/Restrict` can only be performed on a single folder items. There is no way to do joins.

You can, however, create a search folder using [Application.AdvancedSearch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.advancedsearch). You can specify more than one folder in the `Scope` parameter. Keep in mind that AdvancedSearch is asynchronous, so you'd need to subscribe to the `Application.AdvancedSearchComplete` event.